# How to i add an elements dynamically in ionic2/angularJS

Tags: angularjs, dom, ionic2

I want users to be able to add elements such as user inputs with ionic 2/angular. For example with normal JS I would use this code:

```
function addDestination(){
        var destDiv = document.getElementById('destPlaceholder');
        destDiv.innerHTML += '<ul class="rounded"><li><input type="text" class="node" placeholder="text" id="d" /></li></ul>';  
    }
```

how would I go about doing this with ionic2/angularJS?

Comment: As with most things regarding angular, create a model which represents the items. I would think an array would nicely represent a collection of things. Then bind a list of inputs to it using `ng-repeat`. When the user indicates they want another, add an item to the array.

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic2/Angular2 you would, in your page/component's template (html), use a ngFor directive to render HTML elements for every item in an array.

In your typescript you can then just push an element to this array and it will be rendered as an extra element of ngFor.

For your code:

in your template:

```
<ul class="rounded">
    <li *ngFor="let item from items">
        <input type="text" class="node" placeholder="{{item.someattribute}}" id="{{item.id}}" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

in your typescript:

```
public items:any[] = [];

addDestination() {
    this.items.push({id: 1, text: "the item's text"});
}
```

Definitely have a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: So this succeeds in generating new input boxes. But the addDestination() function should only generate input boxes NOT store the data. Once all of the input boxes have been filled I need a separate function that stores all of the inputs into an array. Can you please look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808024/how-to-generate-fields-and-store-user-inputs-into-an-array-ionic2

Comment: Oh I see, well, for the model binding this is the easiest approach by far. Can't you use the data structure from the example above as an input for the real save method?